# What is the role of representation in medieval vs modern epistemologies?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy

What is the difference in the role and in the notion that representation had in the middle age epistemologies vs the modern ones?

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point for your research would be the [SEP Article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/representation-medieval/) on the subject.

I don't think any of us will be able to condense it down much more than that.

Answer (score 2):

For medieval philosophers like Augustine and Aquinas the Latin breaks down where subjectivity pertains to the external world, while objective is representative of the internal relations of persons and the mental life.  Starting with Descartes there is an inversion of these metaphysical terms.  Subjectivity represents human consciousness and the objective gets symbolized as the external world.  There is a clear difference in orientation regarding what can be objectified and brought under the purview of being a subject, while dealing with the dogma of subject-predicate logic.

Answer (score 1):

It could i think be argues that it played no roll. The middle age is typically taken to be from the 5th to the 15th century. In *The Order of Things* Foucault concludes that the episteme which first included a representational conception of signs didn't emerge until the 17th century.

are you able to be more specific about maybe a particular person's work, or a particular time?

Comment: I can't because I don't know. I've always thought, as you said, that representation was a characteristic of modernity. But I saw someone arguing that it was a characteristic of the middle ages, so I thought that maybe it had a different role then (I don't know much about middle age philosophy).